# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS install failed. swap partition failed

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, laptop, swap

I recently was lucky enough to get a laptop for free. The only setback is it had no operating system. I burned ubuntu 12.04 LTS to a disk, and when i boot it in the laptop it loads. I tried installing it a few times, but during the installing process it says there was an input/output error. so after hitting retry a few times it still didnt work so i clicked ignore. While the actual installing process happens it says failed to create swap partition. I dont have any other os on it nor do i think i will (besides ubuntu). If anybody knows how to fix these errors i would be extremely happy.


Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

An I/O error when creating a partition suggests a hardware problem -- most likely a dead or dying hard disk. You can test this by running a SMART test with a tool like GSmartControl or `smartctl`, but the results can be difficult to interpret. You may want to run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda > output.txt` (which generates a report on `/dev/sda`), post `output.txt` to a text file-sharing site, and post the link here for interpretation.